# redirect a domain to a certain folder (Joomla Site)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website hosted in cpanel. Files of this website are in a folder. In the panel there is no possibility to host a domain to this folder, so when I go to www.mydomain.com I can see all folders. I would like to redirect my registered domain to a folder where my website is.

I use htaccess file and try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.hostdomain.com/folder/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work.

This:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

and still nothing.

What I do wrong? I would be grateful for some advice.

**Edit:** I dealt with it.

I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

then in order to hide joomla folder I add to joomla htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

and next I change configuration.php file in joomla folder:

```
var $live_site = 'http://www.mydomain.com/';
```

It works.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your shared hosting?

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't work ;-) You have to tell us _exactly_ what error you get or what is returned when you type in an example `htyp://www.mydomain.com/somevaliduri` into your browser

Comment: ThinkingMonkey, yes it is. TerryE "doesn't work" means "nothing happens":-) When I go www.mydomain.com I can see all folders when I go www.hostdomain.com/folder or www.mydomain.com/folder I can see my website.

Answer (score 1):

test it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/path/to/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  path/to/folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The `RequestCond` should read `!^/path/to/folder/`.  Note the leading /

Comment: Another neat way is to drop the cond and use a negative lookahead in the rule pattern e.g. `^(?!path/to/folder/).* path/to/folder/$0`  Understand how this works?

Comment: @TerryE no!, can you give a doc about it, Please!

Comment: Death, I see that you use PHP.  The mod_rewrite regexp engine is almost identical to the PHP PCRE engine so the PHP doc pages on this are fine. So Lookahead assertions are described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).  Hope this helps. :)